# Specifying python files for jupyter notebook on a Spark cluster

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

I am running a jupyter-notebook on a Spark cluster (with yarn). I am using the "findspark" package to set up the notebook and it works perfectly fine (I connect to the cluster master through a SSH tunnel).
When I write a "self-contained" notebook, it works perfectly, e.g. the following code runs with no problem:

```
import findspark
findspark.init()

import pyspark

sc = pyspark.SparkContext(appName='myApp')
a = sc.range(1000,numSlices=10)
a.take(10)
sc.stop()
```

The Spark job is perfectly distributed on the workers. However, when I want to use a python package that I wrote, **the files are missing on the workers**.

When I am not using Jupyter-notebook and when I use *spark-submit --master yarn --py-files myPackageSrcFiles.zip*, my Spark job works fine, e.g. the following code runs correctly:

**main.py**

```
import pyspark
from myPackage import myFunc

sc = pyspark.SparkContext(appName='myApp')
a = sc.range(1000,numSlices=10)
b = a.map(lambda x: myFunc(x)) 
b.take(10)
sc.stop()
```

Then

```
spark-submit --master yarn --py-files myPackageSrcFiles.zip main.py
```

**The question is**: How to run main.py from a jupyter notebook? I tried specifying the .zip package in the SparkContext with the *pyfiles* keyword but I got an error...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I tried specifying the .zip package in the SparkContext with the *pyfiles* keyword but I got an error

It is camel case:

```
sc = pyspark.SparkContext(appName='myApp', pyFiles=["myPackageSrcFiles.zip"])
```

Or you can `addPyFile`

```
sc.addPyFile("myPackageSrcFiles.zip")
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this with spark session builder?